# Crystal Report and C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

When I run my [C# windows form application](https://prntscr.com/k4414y) that contains Crystal Report. It's asking me to enter the [credential for the MySQL db](https://prntscr.com/k4417o) every time. Even though I entered the correct user name and password. it is saying my user name or [password is wrong](https://prntscr.com/k4419u). I have checked the credential many times and entered password is correct.

Comment: If you use databaset in crystal report then username and password window will not appear or you can set connection string in C# code then username and password window will not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this instruction.

```
            TableLogOnInfos TableLogOnInfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
            TableLogOnInfo TableLogOnInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
            ConnectionInfo ConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            Tables Tables;
            ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "ServerName";
            ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "Database";
            ConnectionInfo.UserID = "UserId";
            ConnectionInfo.Password = "Password";
            ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
            string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport Path");
            report.Load(reportPath);
            Tables = report.Database.Tables;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in Tables)
            {
                TableLogOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
                TableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = ConnectionInfo;
                table.ApplyLogOnInfo(TableLogOnInfo);
            }
            CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
```

When Report will load in meantime always connection string will set.

Comment: Hi, 
 In the Same windows application. When I publish this application to the client computer. Crystal report not loading and getting below mentioned error message. On the developed PC everything  working fine. Can you advice me on this. Please.

Comment: Install same version of Crystal Report in Client computer. @Gihan Amith Kumara

Comment: Hi, 
 In the Same windows application. When I publish this application to the client computer. Crystal report not loading and getting below mentioned error message. On the developed PC everything  working fine. Can you advice me on this. Please. https://prntscr.com/kfcnwy

Comment: Database connection problem. @Gihan Kumara

Comment: Hi @Noor All Safaet
here is my code https://prntscr.com/khpne0
If I change ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "localhost"; to ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "127.0.0.1"; I'm getting same error just like I'm getting on a client pc.

Comment: I have to see @Gihan Kumara

Comment: If I give you a remote session, could you help me. It's a big help. I was struggling on this more than a month now. 
If you have time please give me  buzz on whatspp +94702758031